# UTC seconds for the current date should give the UTC date when it is again converted to Date using these UTC seconds . 

Tags: javascript, html

When i use the UTC() function to get the the total seconds from the epoch time (1 jan 1970) . But again converting the same seconds to Date using "new Date(milliseconds)" constructor is not giving the UTC date . (As second aare as per UTC time)  .

I am at India (GMT +05:30 )
Following is my Html file

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>GMT Calculator</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function calcGMT(form) {
     var dt = new Date(); 
     var sc =Date.UTC(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),dt.getHours(),dt.getMinutes(),dt.getSeconds()) ;
alert("date is "+new Date(sc));
}

window.onload = calcGMT;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also found one thing that it is giving "date is Wed Jan 25 2012 01:02:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" for time 19:32 which is more than the current time by 5:30 . I didn't understood what is happening . It should give the time of UTC Date string as per function "toUTCString()"  Tue, 24 Jan 2012 14:02:17 GMT which is 5:30 less than current time .

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify UTC when you write the date string, you'll get the string in local time.

```
alert("date is "+new Date(sc).toUTCString());
```

Comment: But this Date contructor gives you the date which is just after the milli seconds from 1 Jan, 1970 . So if these seconds is UTC seconds for UTC date for now . then When we use this Date constructor using this seconds  , this should give covert those seconds into exact date that would be UTC date .

Answer (score 0):

Like always when someone struggles with the crappy Date API, I recommend [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)